# openssl s_client -connect defaulting to subdomain?

Tags: android, linux, apache, ssl, openssl

I have spent the last two days trying to figure out why my android application was getting a "no peer certificate" exception error when connecting to my website with the following code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://mysite.co.uk/android/login.php");
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
```

I have used the SSL Labs checker and my certificates pass with a grade A and no issues with the SSL chain (I have read many posts on here claiming this to be the problem). Anyway, thinking that it was something wrong with android I was trying many different suggestions.

I spotted a suggestion to enter the following command into my server:

```
openssl s_client -connect mysite.co.uk:443
```

When looking at the results, it was printing out the self-signed certificates of my design site! Obviously this is not what is expected!

Here are the three virtual host config files for my main site (domain and www) and then the design site

**mysite.co.uk.conf**:

```
# domain: mysite.co.uk
# public: /home/user/public/mysite.co.uk/public

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mysite.co.uk
  ServerAlias *.mysite.co.uk
  RedirectMatch permanent /(.*) https://mysite.co.uk/$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000;"

  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mysite.co.uk/mysite.co.uk.crt
  SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mysite.co.uk/gs_intermediate_ca.crt

  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
  </Directory>

  <Directory "/home/user/public/mysite.co.uk/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin admin@mysite.co.uk
  ServerName mysite.co.uk

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /home/user/public/mysite.co.uk/public

  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /home/user/public/mysite.co.uk/log/error.log
  CustomLog /home/user/public/mysite.co.uk/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**www.mysite.co.uk.conf**:

```
# domain: www.mysite.co.uk
# public: /home/user/public/mysite.co.uk/public

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.mysite.co.uk
  ServerAlias *.www.mysite.co.uk
  RedirectMatch permanent /(.*) https://www.mysite.co.uk/$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000;"

  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mysite.co.uk/www.mysite.co.uk.crt
  SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mysite.co.uk/gs_intermediate_ca.crt

  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
  </Directory>

  <Directory "/home/user/public/mysite.co.uk/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin admin@mysite.co.uk
  ServerName www.mysite.co.uk

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /home/user/public/mysite.co.uk/public

  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /home/user/public/mysite.co.uk/log/error.log
  CustomLog /home/user/public/mysite.co.uk/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**design.mysite.co.uk.conf**:

```
# domain: design.mysite.co.uk
# public: /home/user/public/mysite.co.uk/design/public

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName design.mysite.co.uk
  ServerAlias *.design.mysite.co.uk
  RedirectMatch permanent /(.*) https://design.mysite.co.uk/$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/design.mysite.co.uk/apache.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/design.mysite.co.uk/apache.key

  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
  </Directory>

  <Directory "/home/user/public/mysite.co.uk/design/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin contact@mysite.co.uk
  ServerName  design.mysite.co.uk

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /home/user/public/mysite.co.uk/design/public

  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /home/user/public/mysite.co.uk/log/error.log
  CustomLog /home/user/public/mysite.co.uk/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This also sits in my apache config file

```
SSLUseStapling on
SSLStaplingResponderTimeout 5
SSLStaplingReturnResponderErrors off
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mysite.co.uk/gs_intermediate_ca.crt
SSLStaplingCache shmcb:/var/run/ocsp(128000)

SSLProtocol -ALL +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH
SSLInsecureRenegotiation off
```

When I run:

```
sudo a2dissite design.mysite.co.uk
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and then run:

```
openssl s_client -connect mysite.co.uk:443
```

Then I get the certificate details of mysite.co.uk and my android app works again. Am I missing something here? Why is my server defaulting to the design site?

Comment: Is your site really called `mysite.co.uk`? or is it just an example?

Comment: That is just an example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

because you have multiple hostnames behind the same IP address and each has its own certificate you need to use SNI (server name indication). This sends the required hostname within the SSL handshake. To test this with openssl you have to use the -servername argument, e.g.

> openssl s_client -servername mysite.co.uk -connect mysite.co.uk:443

While all current browser use SNI by default, it looks like that android does not use SNI by default and thus will probably get only the certificate from the default server. I'm not an android programmer myself, but there are several discussions about SNI with android on stackoverflow and elsewhere which indicate, that it might be possible but probably not with the DefaultHTTPClient class.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me in the SNI direction! I did some googling and found this `http://blog.dev001.net/post/67082904181/android-using-sni-with-apache-httpclient-library` which adds SNI to `ApacheHttpClient` class. I have renamed my sites to take off the 000- prefix (see comments in nrathaus' answer) and got the `no peer certificate` message back, added in the class in the link above and hey presto, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that you are using SSL on two different domains, that share the same IP address.

Since SSL is done PRIOR to the web services (HTTP), the SSL cannot know if the user is accessing `design.mysite.co.uk` or `mysite.co.uk`, it just knows it is accessing site on `IP A`, so it is handing the certificate it has, which if I read correctly is for `mysite.co.uk`.

Then the HTTP session starts, and the browser confirms whether the provided certificate matches the URL, when you access `design.mysite.co.uk` it doesn't, when you access `mysite.co.uk` it does.

Solution:

Get another IP address and provide it to one of the sites, thus splitting your web site's SSL access to two separate IP addresses, which each will provide a difference certificate.

Comment: I'm not so sure on this one. I have just changed the names of my config files so that they are in alphabetical order relative to importance so mysite.co.uk.conf is now 000-mysite.co.uk (so comes before design.mysite.co.uk) and I disabled the old site and enabled the renamed one... now it is all working. I have no idea why this works, thought I would share the info with you to see if you can shed some light on it. I did not know that apache orders sites by alphabetical order!

Comment: What did you do before? `reload` apache or `restart` it?

Comment: I always use `restart`, what difference would `reload` make?

Comment: `reload` and SSL don't always mix, especially when you add encryption/remove it. Apache is saving time by not reloading everything, rather just reloading the configuration. Since SSL requires restarting of the port listener, i.e. killing the whole server and starting it again, it doesn't do it.

Comment: OK so using `restart` wasn't the cause/fix to this problem? Just trying to make things clear for future readers. I think I might write up the changes I just made that has it all working and mark that as the answer?